# Grant execute privilege to stored procedure on SQL Azure

Tags: stored-procedures, azure, azure-sql-database

I recently added a stored procedure to my SQL Azure database. I added that procedure logged in as username1. However, I need to allow username2 the ability to EXECUTE that stored procedure. From what I can tell, username2 cannot see/execute the stored procedure. However, username1 can.

What command do I need to run to allow username2 to execute my stored procedure? I'm confident that it's GRANT. However, I'm not sure of the syntax. Can someone please give me an example?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have the same options as if you where using an SQL Server database. You need to GRANT the user proper privileges. Log in as `username1` and execute the following:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON Nameofyourprocedure TO username2;
```

For more help on Azure SQL syntax and limitations refer to the following link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336226